# How to ignore rows with multiple condition mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Here is the table above we have.
From here I want all rows except activityTypeId is 4 and sourceId is null.
I want rows with activityTypeId = 4 and sourceId is not 0, but I need to filter out activityTypeId 4 and sourceId 0.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
select * from tbl
where not (activityTypeId = 4 and  coalesce(sourceId, 0) = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It returns rows with activityTypeId = 4 only. I also want all the rows. But need to deselect rows with activityTypeId 4 and sourceId 0. Thanks.

Comment: check my edit. but your question is really unclear. If this is not what you want, please share sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Run this at the sqlite3 command line to obtain the results desired from the dataset.

```
select * from t1 where activityTypeId != 4 and (sourceId is not null or sourceId  = 0);
```

Comment: Please try to avoid creating answers that only contain code, and always try to explain your code with comments or a short description.